# Postfix log notation

Tags: postfix-mta

I am trying to figure out some lines on my postfix logs which I don't understand and I can not tell if I have to worry or not. Below is some of them.

```
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: mac_parse: -=+
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: dict_eval: const  -=+
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: dict_update: verp_delimiter_filter = -=+
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: dict_lookup: parent_domain_matches_subdomains = (notfound)
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: mac_parse: debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: dict_eval: const  debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
    Oct 23 04:11:04 ct603 postfix/smtpd[13492]: dict_update: parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
```

this is another excerpt

```
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_eval: expand $mydestination -> localhost.e-logism.gr, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_update: relay_domains = localhost.e-logism.gr, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_lookup: fast_flush_domains = (notfound)
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: mac_parse: $relay_domains
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: mac_parse: localhost.e-logism.gr, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_eval: expand $relay_domains -> localhost.e-logism.gr, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_update: fast_flush_domains = localhost.e-logism.gr, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    Oct 23 04:13:01 ct603 postfix/smtpd[14208]: dict_lookup: export_environment = (notfound)
```

and another

```
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f1b5c7213c0
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]:  mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-ct603.e-logism.gr
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-PIPELINING
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-SIZE 10240000
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-ETRN
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-STARTTLS
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-AUTH PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN CRAM-MD5
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250-8BITMIME
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: > mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 250 DSN
    Oct 23 04:37:27 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: watchdog_pat: 0x7f1b5c7213c0
    Oct 23 04:37:28 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]:  mail-yw0-f180.google.com[209.85.161.180]: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
    Oct 23 04:37:28 ct603 postfix/smtpd[15200]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/tlsmgr
```

I have seen some of this paremeters in tutorials about configuring postfix. But I don't know what they mean in a log file. For example

```
    dict_lookup: export_environment = (notfound)
```

is this something that I have to worry? Did this action happened from an external user or is a part of my daemon daily routine?

Could you provide me a good link of how to interpret postfix logs?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it configured for Verbose logging.

None of this is a serious issue. If you want it explaining you would need to learn how SMTP protocols and the internal workings operate on a very detailed level.

You need to switch off the Verbose option, by removing the -v option from the file in /etc/systemd/system or /lib/systemd/system that has the calling options in it.